# How do I get all records created by 10% of users?

Tags: postgresql

I have traffic logs from my site.

I want to sample traffic from 10% of the user base.
But each record in the database is a visit, and each customer can have many visits. Getting only 10% of traffic would be incorrect, because 20% of users may generate 80% of traffic.

Table structure is simple

```
user_id, page
```

How do I get traffic from a random 10% of customers without too many nested subqueries?

Comment: Do you have another table that stores all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using MySQL you can try:

```
/* Calculate 10% of the users, rounding up to account for values below 1 */
SET @limit = CEIL((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)) FROM TRAFFIC) / 10);

/* Prepare a statement for getting the traffic */
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT *
FROM TRAFFIC T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT(user_id)
    FROM TRAFFIC
    LIMIT ?
) U
ON T.user_id = U.user_id';

/* Execute the statement using the pre-computed limit. */
EXECUTE STMT USING @limit;
```

Here's a similar implementation in PostgreSQL (based on feedback):

```
SELECT *
FROM TRAFFIC T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id
    FROM TRAFFIC
    LIMIT CEIL((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) FROM TRAFFIC) / 10)
) U
ON T.user_id = U.user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your users are stored in a different table (and the log table's `user_id` is a foreign key to that) you can use the `tablesample` option to get 10% of the users in a sub-select:

```sql
select *
from the_table
where user_id in (select id
                  from users
                  tablesample system (10));
```

If you don't have such a table Jake's query (without the prepared statement) is probably the way to go.

Comment: Good to know. I updated my answer based on your feedback.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger: I think you can remove your MySQL solution as the question is only tagged with `postgresql`